# Scale property CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the scale property. When an image scaling is greater than 9, the image starts to flash when the scaling is increased.

What I try to do is make an image scaling when I scroll. If you need a visual proof tell me and I will add a an image to my question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="file.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo-div" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="logo-img">
<img class="no-flickr" src="Puebafinal-01.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>


body {
    height: 10000px;
    background: url('img.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    /*-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);*/
}
#logo-div {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 60) {
          var sc=$(document).scrollTop();
          var valor =((sc/2)*1.2)/10;
            jQuery('#logo-img img')
                .css({'transform' : 'scale('+valor+')',
                '-moz-transform' : 'scale('+valor+')',
                '-webkit-transform' : 'scale('+valor+')',
                '-o-transform' : 'scale('+valor+')'/*,
                '-webkit-transition':'all 0.1s ease',
                        '-moz-transition':'all 0.1s ease',
                        '-ms-transition':'all 0.1s ease',
                        '-o-transition':'all 0.1s ease',
                        'transition':'all 0.1s ease'*/})
                .attr('src','Puebafinal-01.svg');
                console.log("funciono");
        }
console.log($(document).scrollTop());

        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 59) {
            jQuery('#logo-img img')
                .css({'width':'100%',
                    'height':'100%',
                    '-webkit-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
                    '-moz-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
                    '-ms-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
                    '-o-transition':'all 0.5s ease',
                    'transition':'all 0.5s ease'
                    })
                .attr('src','Puebafinal-01.svg');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so, you want an image to scale up/down as you scroll?

Comment: Your question is not clear: try to provide the picture *Puebafinal-01.svg* you are using, and yes try to make your question clear adding for example an image of what you want to have.

Comment: Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/meziano/pen/ZEYVzMe): copy the *jQuery script* into a file in on your PC named for example main.js, and the css to a file named main.css and of course copy the *html code* into a file named index.html, change the src of the img tag accordingly.
Try ot open the index.html in a browser. If you are satisfied let me add an answer that you than accept. If not tell us about your problem